# Bits and bytes filling

Tags: c++, bit

Having written code in a form:

```
int i = 0xFF;
```

And knowing that on my system int type has 4 bytes, is there a standard way of predicting how those missing bits will be filled into the i variable, that is will it always be filled as:
**0xFFFFFFFF**
or
**0xFF000000**
That is, the above example is concerned with the the fact which asks, can we predict if the rest of bits will be filled with zeros or ones?

Another question is, is there a way to know if it will be filled at the back or from the front that is:
**0xFF000000**  //<<- bits filled at the back
or
**0x000000FF**  //<<- bits filled from the front

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int i = 0xFF;` with 4-byte ints fills 1 byte with FF and the other 3 with 00.

`char i = 0xFF;` on the other hand (with 1-byte char) fills 1 byte with FF and you have no guarentee what the next 3 bytes are (neither their values, nor if they are used for other variables etc. or not).

The byte direction

```
FF 00 00 00
00 00 00 FF
```

is called the "endianess" of your CPU (and the OS, compiler etc. are made that way that they match it). "Normal" computers today are "little-endian", that is `FF 00 00 00`, altough big-endian exists in devices like mobile phones etc.
However, you won't notice the endianess directly in your program: If you compare the int to this values, it will be equal to `00 00 00 FF` which is mathematically correct (or said in the other direction: when you write 000000FF in your source file, the compiler changes it, in reality you're comparing the int value to `FF 00 00 00`). To get the "real" representation, casting to a byte/char pointer and accessing the 4 bytes individually is necessary.

Comment: By convention, `0xFF000000` refers to a single 32 bit value with the highest 8 bits set. This is distinctly different from writing `FF 00 00 00`, which represents 4 bytes, the first of which is set to 255. While clear enough to those already familiar with convention, saying that 0xFF000000 is the little-endian representation of a 32 bit number set to equal 255 is just plain incorrect. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The rest of the bits will be 0, *always*. When stored to memory, this will be represented as `FF 00 00 00` or `00 00 00 FF` - this depends on the endianess of the machine.

The first is little-endian, - `FF 00 00 00` and is *typically* used by Intel machines, though as pointed out in a comment by **Toby Speight**, the IA-64 architecture is able to be configured to use either layout.

The second example is big-endian. - `00 00 00 FF`

Comment: How is little endian related to the company Intel? Each x86/64 cpu uses little endian, doesn't matter if Intel or AMD or ...

Comment: Intel was mentioned as one example of a company that uses the little endian paradigm. Thanks for expanding the list of examples to include AMD.

Comment: Not all Intel machines are little-endian - IA-64 processors are bi-endian (i.e. can be set to either endianness as required).  And 8051 processors are big-endian on the instruction bus.

Comment: @TobySpeight - thanks for the update. I probably read that in an Intel manual somewhere and forgot it. :red-faced: Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0xFF;
```

Is equivalent to

```
int i = 255;
```

Which in the bits is equivalent to

```
0x000000FF
```